# Adding inline Labels to a UIPicker in swift

Tags: swift, uipickerview

I have been searching around and cannot figure our how I can do the following. I have a UIPickerView (as shown in the image) I have modified to allow me to pick the min and seconds from but I would also like to add labels like CountDownTimer UIPickerView (shown) so the user can know the minutes from seconds.

Any ideas on how to add the inline labels.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although not beautiful and probably a better way out there, but you can always create a single value component for "hours" and separately for "min".

```
var hours = ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24"]
var hoursLabel = ["hours"]
var minutes = ["00","15","30","45"]
var minutesLabel = ["min"]
```

You may also want to adjust your column widths... here's an example.

```
//Adjust width of each picker column
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, widthForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat {

    if (component == 1) {
        return 55 //hours label
    } else {
        return 40 // all others
    }
}
```